# Specialized methods vs. using an Enum as additional parameter

Tags: java, api

Java design question.

I have an object that needs to maintain sets of say 4 types of widgets:  active, inactive, invalid, potential.  For each of these types, I have a series of methods that acts on each:  say add, get, remove, etc.

My question is, would it be better to have a series of methods like this:

```
addInactive(Widget)
getInactive()
removeInactive(Widget)
addActive(Widget)
getInactive()
removeInactive(Widget)
addInvalid(Widget)
```

etc...

OR

Should I have an enum inside this class instead:  WidgetStatus and then the consumer would pass in this enum when they need to perform an action.  This would result in only 3 public methods instead:

```
add(Widget, WidgetStatus)
get(WidgetStatus)
remove(Widget, WidgetStatus)
```

On one hand, I like the first using specialized methods because it not only keeps down the number of parameters needed, but it also forces the consumer's hand to explicitly call the method they need.  However, the latter option seems to keep the API simple and makes adding additional status types in the future a bit easier.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the enum you get a cleaner API and much easier maintenance if you want to change the states; there really is no good reason for the first approach.

Comment: I went with this approach.  I think it encompassed the requirements at hand and made the API much simpler.  Thanks to everyone for their input.

Answer (score 1):

**WidgetStatus** is attribute of widget, not a container. May be follow will be good for you

```
Widget.setActive(false);
add(Widget);
```

Comment: +1 don't build a swiss army knife - the container should not have to know anything more about the widget API than it absolutely has to (like the fact they have a "status")

Comment: I agree with you here, but actually the Widget itself doesn't have a 'status'.  This is sort of an in-memory thing.  The invalid, valid, etc. are sort of decided at runtime based on user actions.  So, this way isn't very feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the enum or whatever into some Strategy Pattern that includes the behavior you mention above.  Then your add/get/remove methods will simply delegate to the strategy to perform the action.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: I thought of that too, but I think the Strategy pattern may be introducing unneeded complexity.  Add/remove etc. basically are just putting/removing entries into Sets.  Strategy pattern seems overkill here.